# Count the numbers of multiple characters in word using .count() without for statement in python

Tags: python, count

How Can I count the numbers of multiple characters in word using `.count()`.
e.g.`name = Jay Kim`
`count = name.count("K")`
`print(count)`
then the result is 1
but I want to do like this.
`name = Jay Kim`
`count = name.count("K", "a", "y", "J", "i", "m")`
`print(count)`
when I do this console returns error.

So, how can I count multiple characters using count()? without for statement

`name = Jay Kim`
`count = name.count("K", "a", "y", "J", "i", "m")`
`print(count)`

Comment: What is an "of statement"? Also, in real world, you'd use `from collections import Counter; count = Counter(name); print(count)`

Comment: What do you want the result of `name.count("K", "a", "y", "J", "i", "m")` to be?  Would something like `[name.count(c) for c in "KayJim"]` be close to what you're looking for?

Comment: This is a built-in function of python and it doesn't support doing count of multiple characters, you could however use a for loop. That will solve your problem.

Comment: I guess I was confused for a second. It's not of, it's for.

Comment: `.count` only counts occurences of a single item. There is no way of counting multiple things without using some sort of a loop (most commonly `for`, whether as a statement or as a comprehension, but you could also use `while`, or recursion, for example). `collections.Counter` that I mentioned before has a loop inside it: it is not in your code, but it still exists, so on this level, the question does not make much sense.

Comment: This is an X-Y problem. What is it exactly that you are trying to do? You can't count multiple character counts by calling `count` only once. Why would you?

Comment: The string *count()* function takes one string (substring) argument and, optionally, *start* and *end* values. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Try explaining by way of an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`def char_count(string):
    set_string=set(string)
    set_string.discard(' ')
    sorted_set=sorted(set_string)

    for char in sorted_set:
        counts=string.count(char)
        print(f'{char}: {counts}')




string=input()
string=string.lower()
count=char_count(string)
```

`

Here
we take input and convert it to lowercase. later we def a function and convert the string into set (because set returns unique values)and sort it alphabetically.
Then we iterate for each character in set and count the number of times it is repeated and print it.